# Highlight multiple divs using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a calendar and I'm trying to highlight saturday to saturday on mouseover of any of the days in the month... so if you mousover the monday 7th May it will highlight saturday 5th - Saturday 12th.

I've managed this with the following. The calendar is dynamically generated with php, so each day looks like this:

```
<td class="calendar-day week_number_' . $this_week_number . '">
    <div class="hello" id="day_' . $list_day . '"><div class="day-number">' . $list_day . '</div>'
</td>
```

`'week_number_ . $this_week_number'` is generated for each week saturday to saturday and the saturday shared by 2 weeks has both classes applied, for example the first available week in the year would be `week_number_1` (it's a holiday cottage, so not all weeks will be open). `$list_day` is the date generated for each day elsewhere.

The highlighting happens using the following jquery at the bottom of the page:

```
$('.hello').mouseover(function() {
    var day = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('/modules/calendar/get_week_number2', { month:" . $month . ", day:day, year:" . $year . " }, function(data) {
        $('.calendar-day').siblings('.week_number_'+data).css('background', 'yellow');
    });
});

$('.hello').mouseleave(function() {
    var day = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('/modules/calendar/get_week_number2', { month:" . $month . ", day:day, year:" . $year . " }, function(data) {
        $('.calendar-day').siblings('.week_number_'+data).css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```

This is done in Codeigniter so this jquery is generated and inserted at the bottom of the page, just to explain the php variables in there. And finally `get_week_number2` is a function to determine which week to highlight...

```
public function get_week_number2() {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = str_replace("day_", "", $_POST['day']);
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
    $date2 = strtotime($date);
    foreach($this->weeks_in_year() AS $week_number => $week)
    {
        if($date2 > strtotime($week['from']) AND $date2 < strtotime($week['to']))
        {
            echo $week_number;
        }
    }
}
```

`$this->weeks_in_year()` is another function that generates an array of weeks in the year... but I don't think that needs to be in here... it's getting too long as it is!

So my question is that, yes, this works, but isn't there a better way? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're seemingly using a table, an arguably better way would be to get the hover'ed `td` element's `tr` parent, and apply a style to all `td` children of that row in one fell swoop. That is, instead of figuring out siblings and stuff.

So let's say:

```
<td class="calendar_day">
    <div id="day_1"></div>
</td>
```

You can go:

```
$('.calendar_day').on('mouseover', function () {

    // get the parent TR
    var $this = $(this),
        $row = $this.parent('tr')
        ;

    // then apply a style that highlights every cell in that row
    $row.find('tr').addClass('highlight'); // ... or whatever your logic is

});
```

Then you can just reverse that in `mouseleave`.

Comment: A good point, but the tds needing highlighting aren't all on the same row... its a standard calendar layout.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a "standard calendar layout" where days in the same week are not in the same row. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry, so like an outlook calendar, week starting on either sunday or monday.